# ng-Change equivalent in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to implement **autocomplete** feature in one of my **Gmail Add-on** using Apps-Script.

Example:

> Once the user starts typing in the textbox , an ajax call should go
>   and populate the suggestions matching that criteria.

So, how can we implement this behaviour in Google Apps-Script.

Looking for something equivalent to `ng-change` in old AngularJs.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail Add-ons are something of a sandbox. You can only use widgets and contexts that Google provides (custom UI implementations are not possible). That being said there is support for autocomplete as documented at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/suggestions

Hopefully this is applicable to your use case but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think we can add custom UI implementations as well. You can have a look at this link : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/
Thanks

Comment: @PrateekGupta Not for GMail Add-Ons. Use of HtmlService (ie. client-side scripting) is prohibited iin GMail Add-Ons. See restrictions at the following link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions

Comment: Thanks for sharing this :)